# Opening taskpane programmatically using the function file

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Is it possible to open the taskpane programmatically from the function file? I'm looking for a method which I can call from the function file but so far I was only able to find the automatic taskpane opening documentation, which is unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible as of now.. We can pin the add-ins, but we can't invoke opening the taskpane from another file (function file) through JS. It has to be tied to a ribbon button.